# Не могу вытащить содержимое из ячейки таблицы

Tags: html, jquery

Всем привет, у меня не получается вытащить содержимое из ячейки таблицы html

```html
<table>
    <tr>
     <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #FBFBFB;" class="shop_id">№</th>
     <th style="border-left: 1px solid #FBFBFB;" class="shop_address">Адрес</th>
     <th style="border-left: 1px solid #FBFBFB;" class="shop_phone">Телефон</th>
    </tr>
   <?php

    $shop_query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM `shopping_opportunities`;');

    while ($shop = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shop_query)) {
     
     echo '<tr class="srt_table_shop">';
      echo '<td class="shop_id">'.$shop[id].'</td>';
      echo '<td class="shop_address">'.$shop[address].'</td>';
      echo '<td class="shop_phone">'.$shop[phone].'</td>';
     echo '</tr>';

    }

   ?>
   </table>
```

теперь с помощью jquery вытаскиваю все строчки таблицы, потом перебираю массив сформированный из строчки таблицы, но не получается вытащить значение из самой чейки этой строчки, что делать?

```js
$('#shop_search').keypress(function(){

  var str_search = $(this).val();

  var tr = $('.srt_table_shop');

  $.each(tr, function(){

   var tr_array = this.children;

   console.log(tr_array[1]);
  });
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если я правильно понял, нужно достать текст, а достается текст с тэгами?

Comment: Всё, я сделал уже

Answer (score 0):

jQuery умеет искать по содержимому:

```
$('td:contains("НАЗВАНИЕ КОМПАНИИ")');
```

Чтобы получить значение можно писать так:

```
$('table').find('.shop_address').first().text();
```